# Listview items background

Tags: android, android-listview

How to change the background image for list items, i am able to change only 1 item background at a time.
If there are 6 items on the list and if click on 3 items those 3 items background images should be changed, how it is possible
Below is my code

```
public class Places extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;


    private int selectedListItem = -1;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Vector<String> data; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.places_custom_list_view);
        data = new Vector<String>();

        // Add data as per your requirement   
        data.add("one");
        data.add("two");
        data.add("three");
        data.add("four");
        data.add("five");
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        listView.setDivider(null);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                selectedListItem = position;
                ((EfficientAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // call any new activity here or do any thing you want here         

                    }
               }, 200L);
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));   
    }

    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.places_custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if(position == selectedListItem) {  
                 holder.txtName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbghover);
            } else {
                 holder.txtName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbgnew);
            }

            holder.txtName.setText(data.get(position)); 

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
    }
```

Comment: here you are storing position in selecteditem. now lets think that this selecteditem is arraylist. when you click on item 1 from six item. you have 1 in your selecteditem arraylist, now you select 4th item so now 4th item will be in your arraylist. Now in your adapter class you will get all the values of selecteditem arraylist and you can change those positions color. I think this is very simple login but you need to work out for this. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,it should work logically.(I didn't try it,btw! :P)

```
...
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                EfficientAdapter.saveState.put(position,"selected");                


                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // call any new activity here or do any thing you want here                                 
                    }
               }, 200L);
            }
        });

    ...
    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public static HashMap<Integer,String> saveState=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context)
        {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
               saveState.put(i,"unselected");
            }
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.places_custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }            

            if(saveState.get(position).equals("selected"))
               holder.txtName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbghover);  
            else
               holder.txtName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellbgnew);

            holder.txtName.setText(data.get(position)); 

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtName;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working for me and i did few changes in the code.
in onitemclick i wrote below code to select and deselect the item using your code.
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {selectedListItem = position;                ((EfficientAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
if(EfficientAdapter.saveState.get(position)=="selected"){
EfficientAdapter.saveState.put(position,"unselected");
}else EfficientAdapter.saveState.put(position,"selected");  
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {}}, 200L);}

Comment: in place of saveState.get(i) i have taken saveState.get(position)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on listview item whole listview is getting refreshed.
So if you want to show previously selected items also then need to keep record of all the item selected. and when listview refreshed you need to check that this positions are previously selected or not according to that set your color.

Hope this help you

Comment: Exactly i need the same thing, can you give me sample for this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:background="@drawable/img_list_background_repeater"
```

Comment: with this i am able to change 1 background image at a time, as i mentioned this in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
if(clickWord.size()!=0)
{               
  for(int i = 0;i<clickWord.size();i++){                       

  if(clickWord.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(adListText[position])&&clickIndex.get(i)==position){
    wordChk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_1);

   }
 }              
}
```

Here clickWord is an arraylist of items selected. so when items get selected it will be added in this arraylist and when arraylist is refreshed i check all this using this loop.

Comment: What is adListText, clickIndex and wordChk in this code, i am using custom listview